# Cannot install Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: upgrade

I can install any ubuntu version up to 11.10 64Bit, but trying to upgrade the system became unstable after grub , the mouse keeps jumping. When I try to install from the disk, the only thing tha I see is a pic of a keyboard and a man, few secondas later just a dash blink. I upgrade others computer with 12.04 32Bit without problem.
I have a intel duo core quad 6700 - 4 gig memory - Ti 560 2gig memory and HD Seagate, other WD and DVD RW.

As I have dualboot with Comice OS 4 I could backup all files.

What is wrong with my system?

Thank you
DataFlowUSA

Comment: u mean u cant install 64 bit , but 32 bit works fine?

Answer (score 0):

Press shift and  then F6 when you see the little man and install with "nomodeset"
The first time you run Ubuntu after installation you will need to enter recovery mode (press escape during boot) and update grub.

This sort of problem should not be in an LTS version of Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

i've been using Ubuntu for about 4 years, I never experienced this kind of problem. The computer I'm using is a Intel Core Dual Quad 6700 - 4Gig Mem - 2Gig Nvidia Ti 560.
Fom this long run I installed al sort of Ubuntu - macBuntu, Comice, Ultimate edition, Debian Mint, and never had a sigle problem. 
Since came 12.04 alpha I have the same situation, comes the little man = Keyboard and I press (Shift+F6), it opens the screen to chosse the language after goes to choose the instalation and goes to black screen and just a dash blinking.
If I put a 11.10 I can install, If I put Debian I can install, but it refuses 12.04. Why such discrimination, I'm having this since alpha 1204